# Nginx SSL not working

Tags: nginx

I'm running a debian squeeze webserver with nginx, and i can't get SSL to work. The error that i get isn't from apache, but from the client web browser, with a "Connection timeout error"

I have purchased an SSL certificate from StartSSL, and when that didn't work, i tried generating my own just to troubleshoot. Both yielded the same error, and neither worked and my nginx log isn't showing anything.

My SSL config looks like this:

```
server {
            listen 443 default_server ssl;
            server_name tarror.org www.tarror.org;
            ssl on;
            ssl_certificate      /srv/ssl/nginx.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key  /srv/ssl/nginx.key;

            root /wdata/tarror.org;
            index index.php index.htm index.html;

            location ~ .php$ {
              fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
              fastcgi_index  index.php;
              fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /wdata/tarror.org$fastcgi_script_name;
              include fastcgi_params;
            }
   }
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Open port 443 in your web server's firewall.

Comment: I just figured it out, my router wasn't fowarding connections of port 443 to my server

Comment: I literally just face-palmed. Thanks for saving me some more frustration!

Comment: Roses are red, FML, <3 U. And now this: `sudo ufw allow https && sudo ufw enable`

Answer (score 1):

I'd first try to take the `ssl on;` line out, as that is deprecated since nginx `1.15.0`. Having `ssl` in the `listen` line does the same thing.

From Nginx documentation:

```
Syntax: ssl on | off;
This directive was made obsolete in version 1.15.0. 
The ssl parameter of the listen directive should be used instead.
```

This article worked for me using self signed certificates on Ubuntu:

http://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/configure-nginx-to-use-ssl-certificates/

This shows the config syntax required for SSL based on different versions of nginx.

Make sure Nginx has port 443 listening using `netstat -an`. Also make sure you don't have any firewall/iptables rules that may be blocking port 443.